# Cant click on links in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS. I'm making a website with pushbottns(anchor's). 
I've made some buttons working fine.
Altough i'm now making a nav bar with some anchors inside.
When i open my website i'm able to see those anchors but i'm unable to click on them. I'm having no issues with my other buttons so i don't know how to locate the issue? Could it be related to the nav id?

```css
        .menubalk{
     padding:25px;
    
    }
    .menubalk ul{
     list-style:none;
     display:inline;
     margin-left:0;
     padding:375px;
    }
    .menubalk li{
     display:inline;
    }
    
    .menubalk a{
     color:black;
     background-color:#0072BB;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight:bold;
     padding: 20px;
     border-radius:5px;
    }
    .content{
     background-color:#0072BB;
     border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
     margin-left:175px;
     padding:25px;
    
    }
    p,h2,img{
     margin:0;
    }
    
    nav{
     background-color:#0072BB;
     float:left;
     width:150px;
     border:10px solid white;
     border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    }
    #wrapper{
     margin:0px auto 0px auto;
     min-width:500px;
     max-width:1800px;
    
    }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="../Afbeeldingen/QualitySigns.png" alt="logo Quality Signs" height="300" width="384">
    <div class="logotekst">
    <p>    
    Signalisatie van hoge kwaliteit
    </p>
    </div>
   </div> <!--einde logo-->
   <div class="menubalk"> <!-- begin menubalk-->
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Projectpagina</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CV-pagina</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Extra link</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!-- einde menubalk-->
  </header>  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Productie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Verhuur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plaatsing</a></li>
   </ul> 
  </nav>
```

I hope somebody can help me solve this issue.
Thank you all!

Comment: Your padding: 375px of the ul  is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan Fries' answer is right. The problem was the padding, but I assume that you were using the padding to try to center the top navigation bar.

Here's a slightly improved version of your styling with working links and a centered navbar! Notice that because I used percentages and auto margin, when you resize the browser window, the navbar is still centered.

Good luck!

```css
    .menubalk {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 5% auto auto auto;
    }

    .menubalk ul{
     list-style:none;
    }

    .menubalk li{
     display:inline;
    }
    
    .menubalk a{
        color:black;
     background-color:#0072BB;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight:bold;
     padding: 20px;
     border-radius:5px;
    }

    .content{
     background-color:#0072BB;
     border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
     margin-left:175px;
     padding:25px;
    
    }

    p,h2,img{
     margin:0;
    }
    
    nav{
     background-color:#0072BB;
     float:left;
     width:150px;
     border:10px solid white;
     border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="../Afbeeldingen/QualitySigns.png" alt="logo Quality Signs" height="300" width="384">
    <div class="logotekst">
    <p>    
    Signalisatie van hoge kwaliteit
    </p>
    </div>
   </div> <!--einde logo-->
   <div class="menubalk"> <!-- begin menubalk-->
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Projectpagina</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CV-pagina</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Extra link</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!-- einde menubalk-->
  </header>  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Productie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Verhuur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plaatsing</a></li>
   </ul> 
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding on your `.menubalk ul` selector is `375px` resulting in the element overlapping the links below.

```
.menubalk ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:375px;
}
```

See below for working example

```css
.menubalk{
    padding:25px;

}
.menubalk ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:0px;
}
.menubalk li{
    display:inline;
}

.menubalk a{
    color:black;
    background-color:#0072BB;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.content{
    background-color:#0072BB;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
    margin-left:175px;
    padding:25px;

}
p,h2,img{
    margin:0;
}

nav{
    background-color:#0072BB;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    border:10px solid white;
    border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
#wrapper{
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    min-width:500px;
    max-width:1800px;

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="../Afbeeldingen/QualitySigns.png" alt="logo Quality Signs" height="300" width="384">
            <div class="logotekst">
            <p>             
            Signalisatie van hoge kwaliteit
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>  <!--einde logo-->
        <div class="menubalk">  <!-- begin menubalk-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Projectpagina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CV-pagina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- einde menubalk-->
    </header>       
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Over ons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Productie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Verhuur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plaatsing</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
```